# How to pass JsonResult to view in asp.net mvc

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a business model class that have put some value then business model class to pass in model class properties.Now I want to pass the value in view page. But I can't use Viewbag because its required a collection.That why I can't pass value in view page.

**Is it possible to pass value in view page??**

If possible. how to pass it?

```
    public async Task<JsonResult> GetDeptName(int studentId)
    {
        var model = _scope.Resolve<FormModel>();

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            await model.DeptList(studentId);
        }

        return Json(new {model.DeptId, model.DeptName });
    }
```

Comment: Pretty confusing code. You want to pass an object containing data in properties to your View? Is this in the controller? More details please.

Comment: You can just pass the view model to the page, and access it there?

Comment: You're returning JSON, not a view.  Did you mean to return a view instead?  Or is your client-side page making an AJAX request to this action?  Or something else?  It's not really clear what you're trying to do.

Comment: I would suggest you refer to [Pass (Send) JSON object values from Controller to View in ASP.Net MVC](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Pass-Send-JSON-object-values-from-Controller-to-View-in-ASPNet-MVC.aspx). It might help you fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass concrete objects just like this to the View() as a parameter:

```
public ActionResult YourMethod()
{
    model = new YourModelObject
    {
        // Fill your properties here
    };

    return View(model);
}
```

In the page.cshtml you can set the model like this:

```
@model YourModelObject
```

And use like this:

```
@Html.LabelFor(x => x.YourProperty)
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.YourPropery)
```